# How to restrict only 3 logins using a single account in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing a web app with Codeigniter.

This app has a login page: I want to avoid that more than 3 people enter with the same credentials in the same moment.
how to restrict Three logins using a single account in CodeIgniter using PHP.

Comment: maintain a login table in the database, check the count of it. That's it. On logout remove the entry from the same table.

Comment: put entry on separate table on login and remove entry on logout and you can count and see current login users.

Comment: add some code that you have tried

Comment: youd have to devise a way to reliably find out when their session expires assuming they don't log out.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table like,

```
logins
id user_id login_at
```

When New user will log in, create a transaction for it,
You need to check the count of this table,

if less than or equal to 3 then insert new logged in entry else throw failure message.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with that info and insert when user logins ...

```
CREATE TABLE `login_info` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `username` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    `login_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
    `ip_address` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
);
```

from ip address you can see how many users are login and from which locations.